# Algebraic Curve mapped to a Point

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $S$ be a algebraic surface (so a $2$-dimensional, proper $k$-scheme) and $\mathcal{L}$ a semi ample and globally generated invertible sheaf on $S$.

Since it is globally generated it provides a morphism $g: S \to \mathbb{P}^n$ for $n$ big enough such that $\mathcal{L}= g^*(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(1))$.

Let $E$ a irreducible curve on $S$ (so a $1$-dimensional, proper subscheme of $S$) such that $\mathcal{L} \vert _E \cong \mathcal{O}_E$ holds.

Why does it imply that already $g(E)= \{p\}$. Therefore $E$ is mapped to a point?

Why $g(E)$ can't be also a irreducible curve?

I suppose that we can use the condition $\mathcal{L} \vert _E \cong \mathcal{O}_E$ in some way to show that $g(E)$ can't be a curve, but how?

Comment: I think $\mathcal L|_E\simeq \mathcal O_E$ implies that $C.E = \deg(\mathcal O_E) = 0$ (if $C = g^*(L)$ is the divisor obtained by pulling-back a general line of $\Bbb P^n$). Maybe this can help.

Comment: I'm not sure. Can I "transport" the property $\deg(\mathcal O_E) = 0$ to $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(1) \vert _{g(E)}$? If yes, why is it a contradiction? Sure, $deg(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(1) )=1$, but why $deg(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(1) \vert _{g(E)}) \ge 1$? Was it your argument to deduce a contradiction?

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially projection formula (one can prove this without it, but morally it is the same). If $f:X\to Y$ is a morphism, $L$ a line bundle on $Y$, $C\subset X$ is a curve, then projection formula will say $(C\cdot f^*L)=(f_*C\cdot L)$. So, in your case if $f(E)$ is a curve, one has $f_*E=\deg(f:E\to f(E)) f(E)$ and thus since $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(1)$ is ample, $(f_*E\cdot \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(1))>0$, which gives $(E\cdot L)>0$ where $L=f^*(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(1))$. But, your hypothesis implies $(E\cdot L)=0$. Thus $f(E)$ can not be a curve and so must be a point.

Comment: Can you also argue like this ? Let $s_0,...,s_n$ be a basis of $H^0(S,\mathcal{L})$, then the map $g:S\to\mathbb{P}^n$ is given by $[s_0:...:s_n]$. Its restriction to $E$ is simply $[s_0|_E:...:s_n|_E]$ and $s_0|_E,...s_n|_E$ are sections of $\mathcal{L}|_E\simeq \mathcal{O}_E$ so they are constant since $E$ is proper. Hence the restriction of $g$ to $E$ is constant.