# Pullback of Ample Sheaf is Ample

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $f:X \to Y$ a morphism between schemes and $\mathcal{L}$ an ample sheaf on $Y$.

Why the pullback $f^*\mathcal{L}$ is also ample?

Comment: This is trivially false without further assumptions on $f$ - think about the case of projection from a product. Why do you believe the pullback along any morphism should be ample?

Comment: The background of this question a futher thread of mine: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2778527/algebraic-curve-mapped-to-a-point

Comment: There I tried to use this "property" to deduce a contradiction